# How to make a set of ObjectAnimator loop?

Tags: android

I want to make a Animation like heartbeat, one picture quickly change its ALPHA from 0 to 1 ,and slowly from 1 to 0. I define that in XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="sequentially">
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="1"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:duration="700"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueFrom="1"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:duration="1500"/>
</set>
```

and I use them in Java Code.

```
private void cursorHeartBeatAnimation() {
    Animator animator = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.cursor_heartbeat);
    animator.setTarget(this.cursor);
    animator.setStartDelay(1500);
    animator.start();
}
```

and I want to let them play all the time, How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use "repeatMode" attribute of "set".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:ordering="sequentially">
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="1"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:duration="700"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueFrom="1"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:duration="1500"/>
</set>
```

Or you can it programmatically:

```
Animator animator = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.your_animation);
        animator.setTarget(view);
        animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                animation.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        });
        animator.start();
```

Answer (score -2):

Try [setRepeatMode(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setRepeatMode%28int%29)

```
private void cursorHeartBeatAnimation() {
Animator animator = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.cursor_heartbeat);
animator.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
animator.setStartDelay(1500);
animator.start();
```

}

Comment: @_@, my eclipse don't show the `animator` have method `setRepeatMode(int)`.